# Purge command no longer works in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

So normally I can run the "purge" command in Mac OS X and get a whole bunch of memory back.  But nowadays when I run the command I get something like

```
objc[191]: Class VMUArchitecture is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[191]: Class VMUArchiveHeader is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[191]: Class VMUDebugMapExtractor is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[191]: Class VMUDwarfExtractor is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[191]: Class VMUDyld is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[191]: Class VMUDyLinkerLoadCommand is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[191]: Class VMUDySymTabLoadCommand is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[191]: Class VMUFatArch is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[191]: Class VMUFatHeader is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CHUD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CHUDSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CHUDSymbolication and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

etc, and at the end I get something like

```
WARNING: Could not determine processor information.
WARNING: Could not determine memory controller information.
WARNING: Could not determine Operating System information.
```

Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks